# Creating a runnable jar referencing already installed thrid party jars

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a java application that uses several 3rd party libraries. Up to this point, I've been exporting the java application (using Eclipse) to a runnable jar with those libraries packed into the jar. All has been well, but it started itching me how large the jar is. Considering this jar will be deployed over a WAN to thousands of work stations regularly, it would be best to make the package as small as possible. Where I'm at now, is I have Eclipse exporting the runnable jar and putting the external jar libraries in a sub folder next to the jar. This has considerably reduced the footprint of my application.... but I've come to realize that all of those jars in the sub folder already exist on the systems so it seems to be a waste of disk space to have a copy of them next to my application.

I would think that there would be a way to create a runnable jar that utilizes the CLASSPATH variable to utilize the existing libraries instead of having to have a copy of them nearby. Is there.... Or better yet, is there a better approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to manually specify a Class-Path in the manifest of the runnable jar.  Class-Path entries are specified as URLs relative to the runnable jar location rather than an absolute value.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#classpath

Additionally, when running the executable jar, the "-cp" parameter, and CLASSPATH environment variable will be ignored.  The class path is set from the Class-Path line in the manifest.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html